# How to use make install or uninstall inside a makefile?

Tags: makefile, installation, gnu-make

I am writing a recipe to configure and install some software in Ubuntu using makefiles, and I know you need `$(MAKE)` instead of `make` inside the makefile, but is it possible to install a given package just by typing `$(MAKE) install package`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Make` is not a shell, and makefiles are not shell scripts. You really need to remember that - don't try to write a shell script and put it in a makefile.  `Make` is a "declarative" language and not a "procedural" like a script.

You need to understand what files you expect to have after the installation, and what files you have before the installation, and what commands are used to go from the latter to the former.  Then make rules where the former depend on the latter, with those commands in the recipes.

If that sounds like too much work, and it may very well be, then, you need to not use a Makefile, but write yourself a shell script instead, and call it in addition (probably after) using `Make`.

`install` and `package` are not files you expect to have after the installation, so they should not have recipes written for them.  They may be considered "phony" Make targets, but then, you still need to depend them on "real" files, and write detailed recipes for those.